# What is the value of this logarithmic/trigonometric expression?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

I need the value of this expression, when simplified.

$$ \log_{10}(\cot(1)°) + \log_{10}(\cot(2°)) + \cdots + \log_{10}(\cot(89°))$$

All the $\log$ have base $10$.

Comment: Hint: $\log (cot x^{\circ})+\log (\cot (90^{\circ}-x^{\circ}))=0.$

Comment: @Anurag A How ? Please explain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$$\log(\cot\theta) + \log(\cot(90-\theta)) = \log(\cot\theta) + \log(\tan\theta) = \log(\cot\theta\tan\theta) = \log(1) = 0$$

Answer (score 7):

The sum is essentially 
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=1}^{89} \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{k \pi}{180}\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{k \pi}{180}\right)\right) + \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) + \sum_{k=46}^{89} \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{k \pi}{180}\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \left[\log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{k \pi}{180}\right)\right) + \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{k \pi}{180} \right)\right) \right] + \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{k \pi}{180}\right) \, \tan\left(\frac{k \pi}{180}\right)\right) + \log_{10}\left(\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{44} \log_{10}(1) + \log_{10}(1) \\ 
&= \sum_{k=1}^{45} \log_{10}(1) = 0. 
\end{align}

Comment: Fully explained, nice. But, You are finding the sum from 0° to 90° instead of 1° to 89°

Comment: One more thing, could you write the answer without summations? I'll accept it!

Comment: And why are you converting the degrees into radians?

Comment: There is a mistake between 2nd and 3rd line because $k=45$ does not have a matching term in the second summation. Luckily it does not affect the final result because it is zero.

Comment: @RaviPrakash It's really from $1^\circ$ to $89^\circ$ already.  At $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, the summand would be $\log_{10}(0)+\log_{10}(\infty)$.  So we just need to adjust the claimed limits of summation to match the actual limits of summation.

Comment: Changed the limits and fixed the offset counting of terms.

Answer (score 4):

Another take on this is of course to show it graphically:

[image: log(cot(θ))]

[image: Running Sum of log(cot(θ))]

I find this helps to add some intuition to the excellent answers already posted.